# Are commenting, editing, voting, reviewing considered as "activities" on the site or not?

Tags: support

**Are commenting, editing, voting, reviewing  considered as "activities" on the site or not?**

Are asking questions and answering considered the only activities for a user?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71622/discussion-on-question-by-rickross-are-commenting-editing-voting-reviewing-co).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan These comments are no longer needed after my edit. Then instead of deleting them all why did u move them to chat?

Comment: I just saw that the comment thread was getting too long so I moved comments to chat.  Anyway if you don't continue the conversation the chat room will go away on its own.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well i have flagged them for deletion.And flags were valid too and that's why they were not rejected. But even after flags are accepted, instead of deleting the comments (which was what i flagged them for) comments are kept. I don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: That might have been a consequence of how the flagging system works.  If a post or comment is flagged and the post or comment is subsequently deleted by a moderator, then the flag is automatically marked as accepted.  So if you flagged them for one reason and I deleted them for another reason, it would still show as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, all are different nature of activities. Q&A is the prime ones.

If we click on our profile, then there is an **"Activity" tab**, which contains following items:

[image: screenshot from mobile showing activity tab in the profile]

"Votes" is also part of it, but not visible in mobile view in a shot.

The "all actions" is further distributed to:

[image: Screenshot from mobile showing all actions]

Comment: How about replacing screen-shots of an android app with that of desktop-site?

Comment: @Pandya, both should be giving same info. You may edit, if it adds value.

Answer (score 2):

Editing, participating in reviews and deletion etc., are considered activities and more important then questions and answers. They come under moderation. Participating in reviews is helpful because they help in keeping the site clean.

Moderation from user side is an important part for Stack Exchange because it is [moderated by us](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) and the appointed moderators alone. So, it is very important to participate in reviews and editing. For being helpful to the site, SE also awards us some [badges](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for useful edits and reviews.

Commenting is considered participation and also an activity. We also get badges like Commentator, Pundit for posting useful comments. Some new users think that comments asking sources or for improvement of the post is targeting them (Own experiences in the past) but it should be understood that it is also a part of moderation which helps for the quality of the site.

Apart from these upvoting and accepting are also activity. Accept is also a kind of vote.

So, there is no doubt that comments, participation and edits are also activities.

Comment: "more important than questions and answers"?

Comment: @Pandya Yes i also do not understand how these activities can be more important than Qs and As when they are dependent on Q-As. If there are no Q-As what to vote upon? what to edit? what to comment upon?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, nothing is more important than Q/A in the model of SE. I would say one step further: Technically Question is more important than Answer!! So, questions are the core things to run the SE model.

Comment: @Pandya Yes, everyone will answer and question and answer. Review queues are like law and order. Reviewers are like crime fighters. That is why moderation is important. In that sense, review are more important than questions and answers.

Comment: @Rickross See the above comment. ^

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, indeed moderation is much important activity, that's why I upvoted your answer. Actually I feel no other Q/A site have well moderation like SE. And yes, reviewing is the best moderation activity, see [this FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258460/260388). Btw, I think it may not be said more important than Q/A since the SE is afterall Q/A model.

Comment: @Pandya "Yes, indeed moderation is much important activity," If u meant more important than Q/A then that can not be the case. If there are no Qs what to moderate?