# When comments are "no longer needed", instead of deleting them all why were they moved to chat (inspite of being flagged for deletion)?

Tags: support, moderators, comments, flagging

After i had made the revision#3 in [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1094/4732), all the comments that were then there under it, became "no longer needed".

And, so i flagged few of them in order to get them deleted. But they were instead moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71622/discussion-on-question-by-rickross-are-commenting-editing-voting-reviewing-co).

**Question-** Was it the right thing to do to move "no longer needed" comments to chat or they should have been all deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Comments marked as "no longer needed", are to be **deleted, if the flag is acceptable.**

["Not constructive" => "Rude or abusive" or "No longer needed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303211/163449)

> ... so regardless of which flag you use, it's essentially just a bat signal to mods that "this comment should be deleted"

In fact this particular flag is introduced for making deletion easier.

---

Comments are moved to chat when there are too many of them (bit noise), however they are still relevant to the Qn's present revision.

Usually, answers are retained even if the Qn changes revision. But comments are temporary & ought to be deleted, when they are no more relevant.

---

IMO, in your case, the original comments should have been deleted, but since they are not, the comment containing chat room link can be flagged as "no longer needed", should you don't want any traces of them.

Comment: but since they are not, the comment containing chat room link can be flagged as "no longer needed". -- This part is not needed for answering the current Q but anyways, i agree with the other things that u have said. And, i am waiting for one Mod to answer it as well. After that i will decide what to accept.

Comment: @Rickross, Actually that advise part is needed, especially for new audience. Since those comments are moved to chatroom, they are under different guidelines. Those comments should be flagged if and only if they break "be nice" policy. Which they aren't. So if you intend to get rid of those comments, then instead of flagging them in chatroom, you may want to flag the comment containing the link to chatroom. Then it's Mod's discretion to decide.

Comment: Ok keeping it or not keeping it actually not affecting anything here so it's ok, but my Q here is simply this- " Was the act of moving comments, that are no longer needed (and flagged as well for the same reason), to chat correct or not or they should have been deleted?" So, i want the answer to precisely focus on answering this query. Anyways you've done that too.

Comment: "so regardless of..." I think Rand'al Thor was talking about a specific post and not in general. For that post in meta, the comment was both rude and NLN but here, they are not the case. The comments Rickross flagged comments but they were not rude I think. NLN works for Rude but rude doesn't work for NLN. The room will be frozen anyway. Why bother if there is no activity?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, Yes I also say the same. The comments are not rude, hence they can't be flagged in the chat room. However the comments should have been deleted at first, when marked as "No longer needed" & if Mod agreed to it. Moving the comments to chat room, is still keeping their trace. Which probably makes people curious about what the Qn originally wss; rather than aware about, what the Qn now is. May be that's why OP asked.

Comment: Well. this happened to me in the past even when the comments are rude. I haven't raised meta posts. I would not care whether NLN comments are moved to chat or deleted. The room will be frozen and deleted too. So, I would ignore rather than stretching to the meta. Speaking of the previous revisions of that question, that was a blatantly off-topic question and it had upvotes on it and no close votes. This shows how people are aware about meta. Having idea about previous revisions will help to understand what happened.